# List of IP addresses used by Twitterbot

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to find a method for validating that a request actually comes from the Twitterbot, since it's trivial for someone to change their user agent to be "Twitterbot/1.0". [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553) and [Bing](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2012/08/31/how-to-verify-that-bingbot-is-bingbot/) ask you to do a reverse DNS lookup to check, Facebook [has a whitelist which is updated often](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler), but I can't find anything for Twitter.

I found someone asking [this same question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/card-crawler-ip-address/15855) on the Twitter developers' forum, but it was over two years ago, so I don't trust the source to be up-to-date or reliable.

Is there an official whitelist, or other verification method for Twitterbot?

Comment: There's an "official" list of IP addresses at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/troubleshooting-cards (search for the string, "IP ranges").  In my experience, Twitter's documented IP ranges don't cover all of the traffic twitter sends, but querying by ASN (which that document also lists) is more complete. 
 e.g., see https://bgp.he.net/AS13414#_prefixes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just had an "twitterbot attack" on one of our customer's sites with 200+ requests in 40 seconds from Twitter alone from 6 different IPs:

```
199.16.156.124 
199.16.156.125 
199.16.156.126 
199.59.148.209 
199.59.148.210 
199.59.148.211
```

Searching if these were legit I found your question, but also the list you are referring to. So it seems that those IPs are still in use.

I'd wish they wouldn't brute force in such a way. Come on, using 6 IPs to index one website? (sorry, frustrations here ;-)

Anyway, when validating the request using HTTP headers just remember that those can be spoofed easily also.